# Django - order queryset result by update time of instances

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Is there a way to order result of a model queryset by update time of its instances? i.e. the instance that has been saved most recently comes first and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a timestamp field to your model. For example in my own code I add a date_updated field for this very purpose.

Your custom models don't have this by default so you have to add it.

```
last_edit = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You will have to update this in the save method (or another method) of your model.

```
import datetime
self.last_edit = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field on your model that tracks this update time ([more information on this here](http://www.djangorocks.com/snippets/set-created-updated-datetime-in-your-models.html)), then yes, you can just use that in a [normal ordering specification](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

If you don't track updates on your model, no, that is not possible.